# unicodeEncoding.GetBytes in php

Tags: c#, php

Hello i want this code in php, can you help me.

```
byte[] test1 = new byte[j];
UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
test1 = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(data1);
byte[] test2 = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(test1);
```

Have try this

```
 $test1 = mb_convert_encoding($data1, "UTF-16LE");
 $test2 = sha1($test1);
```

Thanks all

Comment: ``UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes`` is used in C# because ``ComputeHash`` only accepts a ``byte`` array (``byte[]``) or ``Stream`` as a parameter. PHP accepts a ``string`` as a parameter. To get the same in C# as PHP, you will also need to convert the returned ``byte`` array to a string. Or, specify ``true`` as the second parameter in ``sha1`` (``sha1($test1, true);``) to get the same result in PHP as in C#.

Comment: Ok and the unicodeEncoding are UTF16LE ?

Answer (score 0):

I run this code and the output are SHA1:D7672B17EE7830F77526DB72540C468E8865CB91

```
        string str1;

        string input = "@ztzeré$!]=°°452345é";
        byte[] bs3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);


        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        str1 = encoding.GetString(bs3);

        UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        bs3 = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(str1);

        byte[] bs2 = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(bs3);
        string str5 = BitConverter.ToString(bs2);
        string str7 = str5.Replace("-", "");

        Console.WriteLine("SHA1:" + str7);
```

Now i run on php this code and the output are SHA1:94D034942FE42A3AD2978F6196223BCBFE87F1F1

```
 $input1 = utf8_encode('@ztzeré$!]=°°452345é');
 $input2 = mb_convert_encoding($input1, "UTF-16");
 $input3 = strtoupper(sha1($input2));
 echo "SHA1:$input3\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 C#
   Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
 PHP
     function EncodingASCII($input) {
      if($input) {
       $output = ''; $b = 0;
       for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        if($input[$i] > chr(127)) { 
         $output[$b] = "?";
        $i++;
        } else {
         $output[$b] = $input[$i];
        }
        $b++;
       }
       return implode($output);
      } else {
       return false;
      }
     }


C#
     UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            bs3 = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(str1);

PHP
    mb_convert_encoding($test, "UCS-2LE", "JIS, eucjp-win, sjis-win");
```